# Smartest way to automate attendence

Tags: automation, mobile-application

So theres an app at work which you have to enter it and tap in a large button to check your attendence.

I wish to automate this process so i thought on a few ways but came into problems, would love the best way/code to do it
Thanks :)

Comment: You may (or may not) find it difficult to find someone to help you cheat at your job, but that aside... What have you tried? In what language? Can you post the code of your attempts? What OS does the app run on? Information and details are key.

Comment: So i first tried to make a code that enters the app and then simulates a touch event on an x,y coordinate, i then realized its not very good because it cant run in the background. Now im thinking capturing the http request it makes (or https) and resending it every day is better (btw its not cheating work im still coming i just hate typing it every damn day haha)